# Are Parens necessary in this: &(Array[id])? Sending element #id's pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If I have an array and want to assign pointer to id'th element of the array are these equivalent?

```
int* hello = &Array[id];

int* hello = &(Array[id]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, parentheses are not necessary, and yes these two are equivalent. Array subscript [has higher precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than Address operator.

Comment: Note that *everything* postfix has the highest precedence, so operators like `->` always apply before infix and prefix operators.

Answer (score 2):

However, in C, it is equivalent to

```
 int *hello = Array+id;
```

(assuming `Array` is an array of `int`-s or a pointer to an `int`).

And I would dare say that using pointer addition instead of taking the address of an array element is more usual, i.e. more idiomatic, in C (but that is a question of taste).

PS. that equivalence is not true in C++, e.g. because `operator +` and `operator []` could be user-defined (but not for pointer to int-s).